# How to place a call from one iphone simulator to another?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator, phone-call

I am new to iphone mobile app development.

I just want to know wether it possible to place a call from one iphone simulator to another.

If so, how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

You can not make call from one simulator to another.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's impossible. You have to use a real devices if you want to test some stuff.